# Magento: Add custom field to grid and populate it

Tags: magento

I've followed this tutorial: http://raghunathgurjar.wordpress.com/2014/04/04/how-add-a-new-custom-field-to-customer-address/ and added custom field to my DB.

What I want is to show the value from that field in Sales->Invoices grid.

I added the column, using this code:

```
$this->addColumn('govt_id',
        array(
            'header'=> $this->__('Govt Id'),
            'align' =>'right',
            'type=' => 'text',
            'index' => 'govt_id',
        ));
```

My questions is how to populate it with the data from the custom added field?

```
    protected function _getCollectionClass()
    {
        return 'sales/order_invoice_grid_collection';
    }

    protected function _prepareCollection()
    {

        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());
        // $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(???);
        $this->setCollection($collection);
        return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }
```

Regards!